# could or can + would?

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood

> If I could make it back to the office, I would come.

Should I use *could* or *can* here?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is correct if you are explaining that you cannot do something that you promised to do.

> Something is preventing me from returning to the office, despite my desire to do so.

The idea can be abstracted as

> If I could, I would; but I can not, so I will not.

---

EDIT: responding to comment regarding can vs could

The could / would pairing implies a known current situation.

> If I could, I would. => If it was possible (near past), I would be doing it. (now)

When replaced by can / will, the sentence becomes about an unknown current situation.

> If I can, I will. => If it is possible (now), I will be doing it. (near future)

Comment: I would change "if it was possible" to "if it were possible" (subjunctive, implying "but it is not").

Answer (score 0):

Telling someone that you may come back to the office: If I can, I will. I'll have to see if my replacement gets here in time.

Telling someone that you want to go to the office but something (outside your control) is preventing me: If I could, I would.  But my boss told me I need to stay here.